# ios5 - xcode 4.4.1 - AddThis configuration

Tags: ios, ios5, xcode4.4, addthis

I am trying to add a social share functionality to my ios application in order to do so, I am trying to install AddThis.

I have followed the Quick Start guide and tried to find a solution myself... it has to be something really obvious.

Based on the guide, I copy the different files to my project, but when I import the class "AddThis.h" in the class I want to use it, Xcode complains saying that the file cannot be found !

To copy the files, I have gone to "File/Add Files" in Xcode. There I check the "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)" box and add the files to the target.

**IMAGES:**

1. Add AddThis lib: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/204/addaddthislib.png/
2. Project Hierarchy: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/690/projecthierarchy.png/

Can anybody please help me? It has to be something really obvious... as you can see I am a new iOS programmer.

Xcode version: 4.4.1
iOS version: 5
AddThis version: 0.2.0

Thanks a mill

Comment: Screen shot of xcode navigator might help

Comment: Question edited @CarlVeazey . Instead of screenshots, I had to add links to images (imageshack) as I don´t have enough permissions to add screenshots yet.

Comment: "Third Party Libs" is part of it yes? Did you follow the instructions regarding that, and made sure they are all in the right folder? Also, do a clean build and go to Organizer -> Projects find your project and delete the derived data. Som elibraries have a header path extension that needs to be made but ther guide doesn't say anything about that.

Comment: Yes, "Third Party Libs" is part of it. In their guide says to copy it, and also some of the folders that are inside separately (I don't know why, isn't it going to duplicate libraries?). 
About the clean build I will try that this evening (I'm at work now..). Also, I haven't build it at all, first I wanted to make sure that I can actually call the "AddThis.h" class. Thanks @CarlVeazey

Comment: no problem... I thought you were getting a build error though? What is the problem you are having then?

Comment: The problem is that when I import the class 
#import "AddThis.h"; 
in the class I want to use it, Xcode complains saying that the file cannot be found.

Comment: Oh, like the as you type compiler errors? Well actually try to build it when you get home. It might just be Xcode freaking out and will build fine.

Comment: Thanks @Carl, I will try again at home. Also, in the installation guide, they say to add "Third Party Libs" folder and then some other libs that are already inside the "Third Party Libs" folder separately. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: yes that seemed strange too. Are those files added to the project / target?

Comment: I have built the project and is working now. I wouldn't have expected this to be honest. Thanks for that @CarlVeazey

Comment: no problem Xcode does that sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building the project has fixed the issue. First I've had to add the compiler tag "-fno-objc-arc" to all the AddThis classes as I'm working on an ARC project.